# svn update does not work, but svn commit and svn checkout works

Tags: svn

I am using svn client (in ECLIPSE Plugin from galileo) and also install svn in my local machine (ubuntu 11.04). I checked out a framework from the local machine in my company, and it works by downloading the whole framework perfectly.

I started working on it, and commit some stuffs to the svn server. It works also fine if I execute commit/checkout from the shell. I did not configure anything for the svn, so I assume it use default configuration.
One thing got quite strange when I delete a file (file.c) from my local copy. Tried to retrieve this file.c from the server, do SVN update. It says sucessful to the latest revision. But I do not see the file.c in my local machine. I checked manually using the url of the svn server, I can see that file.c is there in the svn server. 
Until now, if I delete something from the local copy, I have to checkout the whole framework and recompile everything from beginning just to get the file.c.

It is quite devastating and time consuming.. Does anyone can help me to figure out what I did wrong?

Thank you

--some edit after some thinking

can the admin of the svn server do a config for my username, so I can not do svn update, and just svn commit/checkout?

Comment: When you `svn update` from the command line, does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you accidentally delete the file, not via SVN's delete command, SVN doesn't know you've lost it, as the local SVN database is up to date with your last commit/update.

In your directory do a `svn cleanup` then do an `svn udpate`. The cleanup lets SVN know that the file is missing, then the update will pull it as it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the folder that contains file.c.  Then try revert.